# Decompression of bz2 file fails with error

Tags: compression, apache-nifi, bz2

So far I've tried to decompress using mac command line tool `bzip2 -dc` , it throws this error : 'huff+mtf data integrity (CRC) error in data', I've even tried recovering files using `bzip2recover` command it converted my 4 mb file into 6000 small bz2 [files](https://gist.github.com/JD-V/023b84ac86894db8ea6e54139cd5c4e5) with success message however decompression of all those files failed with the same error

Using python bz2 package : this throws error 'IO error Invalid data stream'

Using Apache nifi, It says Java.io.exception unexpected end of stream.

Data was fed to GSC bucket using this chain 'Palo alto block' -> 'pubsub' -> 'GCS bucket'.

All this indicates that data might be corrupt but I am not sure(can't simply blame Pub Sub). has anyone ever faced similar situation? 
any kind of help will be appreciated.

you can find a sample bz2 file [here](https://gist.github.com/JD-V/023b84ac86894db8ea6e54139cd5c4e5)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is already decompressed?

Can you do a "**tar -tf file.bz2**"?

Or can you try to get the file type, for example with "**file.bz2**"

Comment: Check the link, does it look decompressed?
and 'tar -tf' did not work it says error opening achieve.

Comment: JD-V, i am not allowed to access the link. What tells "file xxx.bz2"?